# Reinterpret data in numpy ndarray

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with dtype=uint8 and shape=(N,4) and I want to reinterpret the 4 bytes along the axis=1 efficiently as dtype=int32 and get a resulting shape=(N,) but nothing I've tried works. The equivalent in c would be brutally casting the pointer of the array.

The initial array is created like this from a pandas dataframe:

`tmp=df[['data_1','data_2','data_3','data_4']].values.astype('uint8')`

But then this works but it's not vectorized:

`tmp1=np.empty((tmp.shape[0],),dtype=np.int32)`
`for i in range(tmp.shape[0]):`
  `tmp2=tmp[i].copy()`
  `tmp1[i]=tmp2.view('<i4')`

And this, which I understand as the efficient way to do it, doesn't:

`tmp1=tmp.view('<i4')`

Giving the error:

`ValueError: When changing to a larger dtype, its size must be a divisor of the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array.`

But the size should be correct as far as I understand.

edit: added the reinterpeted explanation

Comment: When you say "convert" from `(N, 4)` to `(N,)`, you mean you want to drop an entire axis, i.e. three of your four columns? Or do you actually mean, you want the result to be shaped `(N * 4,)`?

Comment: So you want to actually treat each of the N rows as four 8-bit parts of a 32-bit integer?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg what I wrote is correct in that I want a final shape of `(N,)`.

Comment: @DominikStańczak0 yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually want the output shape to be `(N*4,)` (not `(N,)` as you wrote initially), you can just [flatten](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) it and then [cast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) it to your desired type:

```py
tmp1 = tmp.flatten().astype('int32', copy=False)
```

**EDIT:**

If you actually want the *same underlying data* to be interpreted as a different type and get a `(N,)` array out, the [`view`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) method is in fact the way to go. This for example works for me:

```py
import numpy as np
N = 5
a = np.arange(N*4, dtype='uint8').reshape((N,4))
a.view('int32')[:,0]
```

That view is then `array([ 50462976, 117835012, 185207048, 252579084, 319951120], dtype=int32)`.

Comment: The last part is what I want and your little example in fact works (even with '<i4' instead of 'int32') but gives the error in the question with the data coming from the dataframe. But, if only that is the problem, then the error message is wrong I think.